# UIPickerViewで選択中の項目をif比較で使いたい

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode6(Swift)で、PickerViewを設置して、部品下に遷移ボタンを置いたとします。
仕組的には、PickerViewで事柄を選択し、部品下にあるボタンを押すと、選択した事柄の詳細ページに遷移するというものなのですが……

```js
import UIKit

class SecondView: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var stations = ["渋谷", "新宿", "六本木", "東京"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return stations.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
        return stations[row]
    }


    @IBAction func nextThird(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (stations.count == [0]){
             let nextThirdView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tre") as UIViewController
             nextThirdView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.PartialCurl
            self.presentViewController(nextThirdView, animated :true,completion:nil)

        }

    }

}
```

以上のように事柄を「渋谷」「新宿」「六本木」「東京」の４つに設定した場合、
「渋谷」を選択し、ボタンを押した時に「tre」と名付けたViewControllerに遷移したいのですが、

```js
if (stations.count == [0]){
                 let nextThirdView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tre") as UIViewController
                 nextThirdView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.PartialCurl
                self.presentViewController(nextThirdView, animated :true,completion:nil)

            }
```

この一文でつまづいてしまいます。

後半の画面遷移のコードは大丈夫だと思うのですが、肝心のif文の部分がどう書いたら良いのか分かりません。

お詳しい方がいましたら、どうかご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPickerViewの選択中の列を取得して、要素 "渋谷" の配列のインデックスである「0」と比較すべきでしょう。

```
if (myPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0) == 0){
  println("Shibuya.")
}
// myPickerViewはじぶんが接続したUIPickerViewの名前に合わせてください。
```

Comment: myPickerViewは前述している変数「stations」でしょうか？「pickerView」という関数でしょうか？それとも新規に作ったものでしょうか？
どちらにしろ、
途中のコードで要素がStringになっているようなので、
SelectedRowInComponentが使えないみたいです。

Comment: myPickerViewはUIPickerViewのインスタンスです。じぶんの使用しているものに合わせて書き換えてください。

Comment: dokubekoさん、ご回答有り難うございます！
PickerViewのインスタンスを入力してみたら無事解決致しました。
お手数おかけして申し訳ございませんでした。有り難うございました。